# Difference between Facebook post and event?

Tags: facebook

I would like to know what is the best way to promote an event using Facebook. So far we were creating posts and we shared the links for like and share among our team/associates. We got even though the following suggestion from one of our associates :  'Facebook events are better than posts, since every time somebody likes an event, his/her friends are notified ".

What is the difference between posts and events? What are the benefits of each approach?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion given by your associate is partially correct. Not just event, even when somebody likes any post, his/her friends are notified. It's depends on individual's settings.

Now the best to promote an event is, create a public event and promote it by using Facebook Ads. But remember it is paid service.

If you don't want spend money then the way you are doing is right. Keep sharing the link and ask people to react on that (like/comment/reply etc.).

In my opinion, if it is really about an event, then instead of creating a post, create a public event. That is what the purpose of [Facebook Event](https://www.facebook.com/help/572885262883136/create-and-manage-an-event) feature.

Answer (score -1):

The best is an event because the persons can join it and this will bring more people with the notifications, the posts are not engaging people

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).